# How to hash file (MD5, SHA..v.v..) in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, hash, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I'm coding an Universal App, how can I hash a file with `md5` or `SHA` algorithm ?

I searched, found this: `system.security.cryptography`, but it's not available in my project.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In UWP, it is [Windows.Security.Cryptography namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx) and [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx).

In the [CryptographicBuffer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.aspx) there is sample showing how to use this class.

Here is my demo about getting MD5 hash:

```
private string strAlgNameUsed;

public string GetMD5Hash(String strMsg)
{
    string strAlgName = HashAlgorithmNames.Md5;
    IBuffer buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

    HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);
    strAlgNameUsed = objAlgProv.AlgorithmName;

    IBuffer buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg);

    if (buffHash.Length != objAlgProv.HashLength)
    {
        throw new Exception("There was an error creating the hash");
    }

    string hex = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(buffHash);

    return hex;
}
```

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.  Further just hashing a password is insufficient and not secure, a password derivation function such as PBKDF2 (`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`) with an iteration time of around 100ms is required. But the question does not ask about encryption, only hashing.

Comment: @zaph, yes, while OP didn't post any code, I can provide only documents here which I think is not a good answer,  so I put a straightforward demo to deliver the help. If it is about the ECB mode, you're right, it is insecure, I edited my answer to remove the encryption part.

Comment: Actually it was more about the use of MD5 for key derivation. Key attacks are not brute force on the actual key but on the password the key is derived from using lists of frequently used passwords. Because of this key derivation method used must consume substantial CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw this in, just because it is UWP... and if you use storageFolder.GetFileAsync to get to the file, the method will have to return an Async Task or a void. Forgive me if this isn't perfect, I'm more familiar with asp.net. But this does return a valid MD5 Hash on a file that was created in the LocalState folder:

```
private async Task<string> GetMD5Hash()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var storageFolder = localFolder; // await KnownFolders.GetFolderForUserAsync(null, KnownFolderId.PicturesLibrary);
        var file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("signature.png");

        byte[] computedHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path));
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in computedHash)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }
        string result = sBuilder.ToString();
        return result;
    }
```